# Retrieve documents where a given date is not between two fields of type Date with Elasticsearch

Tags: json, java-8, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I have a document in Elasticsearch 7.10.1 with the following mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
     "properties": {
       "id": { "type": "text"},
       "nonAvailabilities": {
         "type": "nested",
         "properties": {
            "startDate": { "type": "date" },
            "endDate": { "type": "date" }
          }
       }
     }
  }
}
```

I want to retrieve all documents where passed date as parameter is not between `nonAvailabilities.startDate` and `nonAvailabilities.endDate`.

I have tried the following query but it returns unwanted documents:

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
       "filter":[
          {
             "bool":{
                "must_not":[
                   {
                      "nested":{
                           "path":"nonAvailabilities",
                           "query":{
                             "bool":{
                               "must":[
                                  {
                                     "range":{
                                        "startDate":{
                                           "lte":"2021-08-19T10:30",
                                           "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
                                        }  
                                     }  
                                  },
                                  {
                                     "range":{
                                        "endDate":{
                                            "gte":"2021-08-19T10:30",
                                            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
                                        }
                                     }
                                  }
                               ]
                            }
                         }
                      }
                   }
                ]
             }
          }
       ]
    }
 }
}
```

I have also implemented this query using Spring Data but it returns also unwanted documents:

```
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
queryBuilder.filter(
      QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
          .mustNot(
              QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("nonAvailabilities",
                  QueryBuilders
                      .boolQuery()
                     .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("startDate").lte(criteria.getWhen()))
                      .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("endDate").gte(criteria.getWhen())),
                  ScoreMode.None)));
 ...
 Query searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(queryBuilder).build();

 reactiveElasticsearchOperations
    .searchForPage(searchQuery, MyDocument.class, IndexCoordinates.of("myDocuments"));
 ...
```

Do you have an idea what is wrong with my query ?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct.

You need to prefix startDate and endDate with "nonAvailabilities".
Fields in nested query should be fully qualified so startDate will be nonAvailabilities.startDate

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
       "filter":[
          {
             "bool":{
                "must_not":[
                   {
                      "nested":{
                           "path":"nonAvailabilities",
                           "query":{
                             "bool":{
                               "must":[
                                  {
                                     "range":{
                                        "nonAvailabilities.startDate":{
                                           "lte":"2021-08-19T10:30",
                                           "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
                                        }  
                                     }  
                                  },
                                  {
                                     "range":{
                                        "nonAvailabilities.endDate":{
                                            "gte":"2021-08-19T10:30",
                                            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
                                        }
                                     }
                                  }
                               ]
                            }
                         }
                      }
                   }
                ]
             }
          }
       ]
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I have also a bad date format pattern. Elasticsearch save document with this format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"` so my request must provide this format pattern.